# Convert a JavaScript Array to a c# class

Tags: javascript, c#, arrays, json

i've got a JavaScript-Arrays of following format

```
['abc','efg','hik','lmn','','',' / ','','',13512,13520,1,'',0,2488934,1,1004,1,'','','1.00']
```

And I want to convert them to a c#-class. I thought this would be possible with Newtonsoft JSON.NET

My first attempt was `List<string> objs =  JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<string>>(stringValue);`

That was working. Now I created a classs

```
 class ArrayData
{ 
   [JsonIgnore]
    public long id{ get; set; }

    [JsonProperty(Order=1)]        
    public String a { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty(Order = 2)]
    public String b { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty(Order = 3)]
    public String c { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty(Order = 4)]
    public String d { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty(Order = 5)]
    public String e { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty(Order = 6)]
    public String f { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty(Order = 7)]
    public String g { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty(Order = 8)]
    public String h { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty(Order = 9)]
    public String i { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty(Order = 10)]
    public String j { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty(Order = 11)]
    public String k { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty(Order = 12)]
    public String l { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty(Order = 13)]
    public String m { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty(Order = 14)]
    public String n { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty(Order = 15)]
    public String o { get; set; } 
    [JsonProperty(Order = 16)]
    public String p { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty(Order = 17)]
    public String q { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty(Order = 18)]
    public String r { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty(Order = 19)]
    public String s { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty(Order = 20)]
    public String t { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty(Order = 21)]
    public String u { get; set; }
}
```

And tried following `var myObj =  JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ArrayData>(stringValue);`

But now I got the error: `Cannot deserialize the current JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) into type 'ArrayData' because the type requires a JSON object (e.g. {"name":"value"}) to deserialize correctly.
To fix this error either change the JSON to a JSON object (e.g. {"name":"value"}) or change the deserialized type to an array or a type that implements a collection interface (e.g. ICollection, IList) like List<T> that can be deserialized from a JSON array. JsonArrayAttribute can also be added to the type to force it to deserialize from a JSON array.
Path '', line 1, position 1.`

Is there no way I can assign a class attribute to an anonymous field of an array just by position with JSON.NET?

Comment: Why do you need it `can I assign a class attribute to an anonymous field of an array just by position`.

Comment: I want to take the results I got from an web request (the JavaScript Array above) and parse it into a c#-class in an efficient and elegant way for further processing within my c# application

Comment: then....do it with an array if it is anonymous

Comment: Just declare an *enum*  `enum{ a=0, b=1, ...}` and use it as an index to your list...

Comment: Can you elaborate what you are meaning with enum? I mostly programm in ABAP and therefore are not that well versed in c#? It is just a small private project of mine to (re-)learn it.

Comment: Just think of it as readonly constants like  `int a=0; int b=1;` Now you can use it as `var someval = objs[a]`

Comment: Now I get it. Sorry was a little bit slow in thinking. Yes this is a possible way to solve that problem. I will give this a try. I was just wondering if there's an more elegant way to solve this task.

Comment: @lichtbringer if it existed, someone would have posted it by now....But wait a little more